# Is this notation$~X(z)=Z\left[x\left[n\right]\right](z)$ correct of Z-transform?

Tags: signal-processing, z-transform

The textbook which I have wrote the below equation of Z-transform.

$$X(z)=Z[x[n]]$$

From the definition of Z-transform, the rightmost term of sigma is held.

$$X(z)=Z[x[n]]=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n  ]\cdot z^{-n}$$

Of course the result of the computations of sigma only has $z$ as a variable so I thought the middle term can be rewritten as below.

$$X(z)=Z[x[n]](z)~~\leftarrow~~\text{Added (z) to emphasize that the function has variable z}$$

Is this notation not general or weird or can be subtracted of score of test?

Comment: You are overthinking this (if I may say). Your notation is fine, but the textbook notation is equally fine. As long as notation is clearly defined, there should not be any problem.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Seems overly burdensome. Though there is no right or wrong, as long as you are consistent.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost possibly no problem for write $X(z)=Z[x[n]](z)$ in tests however I guess that anybody want to abbreviate $\left(z\right)$ as the frequency of write of $X(z)=Z[x[n]](z)$ increases.